Why is the joint density function defined like this, and why can the joint density function be more than 1?
The following comes from a paper (prefer to keep anonymous).

Let there be $n$ independent variables drawn from $[0,1]$. Let $X$ (resp. $Y$) be the smallest (resp. largest) variable drawn. We have that $Pr(X \geq x, Y \leq y) = (y - x)^n$.

So far so good. But then:

Therefore, the joint density function of $X$, $Y$ is given by $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = -\frac{\partial^2 Pr(X \geq x, Y \leq y)}{\partial x \partial y} = n(n-1)(y-x)^{n-2}$.

First of all, why is the joint density function expressed like this? Is $Pr(X \geq x, Y \leq y)$ the joint mass function? If so, why is there a minus sign in front of the derivation? And shouldn't the joint mass function be for discrete distributions (whereas here it's used on continuous distributions)?
Secondly, shouldn't density functions always have values below 1? In the case of $n = 3$ variables, the joint density function can result in higher values, e.g. $f_{X,Y}(0.1, 0.5) = 2.4$.

For Q 2, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok


The negative sign in front of the derivative is because the probability in the first quote has $X\ge x$ instead of the usual $X\le x$. (And joint density functions definitely make sense for continuous distributions.)

Whilte cumulative distribution functions must always be at most $1$, there is no reason that (continuous) density functions must be at most $1$. For example, if $U$ is uniformly distributed on an interval $[0,z]$, then the density function of $U$ is the constant $1/z$ restricted to $[0,z]$, and $1/z$ can certainly exceed $1$. There are many other examples, such as a normal random variable whose density function at its mean equals $1/\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}$, which can certainly exceed $1$ as well.



Could you elaborate point 1?

Also I asked about the joint mass function. You answered one of my questions about it but on joint density functions. (Still concerning point 1.)
